# Debug msbuild custom task with msbuild v15.0

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

[Microsoft's instructions for enabling debugging of MSBuild tasks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/) no longer seem to work. I cannot get `msbuild /?` to show the `/debug` switch, and when I try `dotnet publish /debug` it complains that `/debug` is not a valid switch.

Is there any way to debug MSBuild tasks any more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/debug` feature for msbuild was removed from public builds of MSBuild 15 and the code for it [has later been removed entirely](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/2955).

To "debug" logic in your build targets / msbuild files, your best option is to create binary logs using the `-bl` argument and inspecting them using the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com). It shows you all the inputs/outputs to task invocation and all the steps that happen during Msbuild runs.

Debugging custom tasks (e.g. C# code) is very hard to do. It would involve looping+sleeping until `Debugger.IsAttached` is true for debug builds (and then attaching to the process in Visual Studio) or calling `Debugger.Launch()` (only on .NET Framework, not .NET Core MSBuild).

I suggest separating the actual task class from your logic implementation to allow you to unit test your logic. This should remove the need to debug it during runs.

You can see a sample of both the debugger logic and the separation in [NuGet's PackTask](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/314a51e00e0741beca7f2e6138afed0cc7191091/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/PackTask.cs) and its [PackTaskLogic class](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/PackTaskLogic.cs).