# MSBuild /debug switch not coming with MSBuild v16

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have set the reg key in both the location ,

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0]
"DebuggerEnabled"="true"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0]
"DebuggerEnabled"="true"

I followed this question [Unable to debug msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671179/unable-to-debug-msbuild)

But when I am doing msbuild.exe /? I cannot see the debug switch.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise>where msbuild

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

Comment: Looks like this feature is disabled
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419244/debug-msbuild-custom-task-with-msbuild-v15-0

Comment: Yes, `/debug` feature was removed and there is no such switch for MSBuild now([MSBuild Command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019#switches)). The link you referred to has pointed it and shared some insights.

Comment: Hi @yogesh, I suggest you summarize your comment and write an answer then accept it, other forum members who meet the similar issue can refer to this thread or find the explanation easier. Besides, thanks for sharing the link which explains this issue.